# When launching an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Web App in IIS 8.5 I get an HTTP500 and an Event 1001 against the HttpPlatformHandler

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http, iis-8

I have built and published an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Web App via VS2015 and Published it to IIS 8.5 on a Windows Server 2012 64-bit machine. I had previously published a very simple ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 App (albeit with no EF code) which works fine in IIS and to my mind has proved the IIS config side of things for .NET. To do all of this I followed the really helpful guide that is: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html.
When I try to browse to the published App I get an HTTP 500:
[image: HTTP 500 picture]

Also in the Windows Application Log in Event Viewer at the moment of browsing I get an Event 1001 against the HttpPlatformHandler (I have installed the latest version 1.2)
[image: HTTPPlatformHandler Event 1001 error]

Has anyone got any clue on what might be happening and what steps I could take to resolve this error please?

Thanks

Comment: Update on this - its something to do with Entity Framework as when I added a basic bit of LINQ SQL to the basic working application it stopped working and gave the same HTTP 500 error. Is there logging that could be enabled so I can see more clearly what's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue with the help of my colleagues: I had the DB Connection String set to include “Trusted_Connection=True;” for some reason and when I published the App to IIS on a different Server to the one it was developed on I got the HTTP 500 error. I removed it and it now works!